# Download an old version of Google App Engine SDK

Tags: google-app-engine, download

Where can I find for download an old GAE SDK, say 1.9.15 ? I need to find out coverage and maybe use 3rd party API, which do not work well with the recent version.

Answer (score 4):

It depends if the respective SDK is still officially supported or not. Both kinds are available in the [appengine-sdks](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/appengine-sdks/) GCS bucket.

No longer supported SDKs (like the `1.9.15` one you're seeking) are available in the [deprecated](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/appengine-sdks/deprecated/) folder. Note that they may be under a subdirectory named as the version number without the dots, i.e. `1915` for `1.9.15`).

Still supported SDK versions are available in the [featured](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/appengine-sdks/featured/) folder.