# In Python dev_appserver.py Development server not start

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, sympy, google-app-engine-python

I am using Windows 10 and I am completed all the process given by `sympy-gamma` document https://github.com/sympy/sympy_gamma/ . but at the end when i am configuration file for App Engine (needed to run the development web server):

> $ python deploy.py --generate-only --generate-test 1000

and run development web server and run this code will give me error:

> $ dev_appserver.py .

server is started but port 8080 Display:-

```
This page isn’t working

localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

[Error display in terminal:-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHlj2.png)

Comment: it seems it can't find the module `sympy` for whatever reason. Could you give us some more input on your projects structure etc.

Comment: @Phanti ya sure. visit this site  https://github.com/sympy/sympy_gamma/ and download the source code and follow that steps for run that code on server. i just follow that docs given by sympy-gamma but my server not start can you please help me?

Comment: Please don't post images of text, instead copy-paste the text in your post and format it accordingly. Thx.

Comment: FWIW, the GAE SDK version 1.5.1 mentioned in that recipe is very old, you may want to use [the latest- 1.9.87](https://storage.googleapis.com/appengine-sdks/featured/GoogleAppEngine-1.9.87.msi) or a more recent one, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45174082/4495081. But I'm unusure if that's related to the error.

Comment: As @Dan said, in the readme of the repository you provided it says : "Download and unpack most recent Google App Engine SDK for Python from". The lines of code from below are just an example, for that time. Could you please try to the latest version of GAE SDK and, after that, confirm that the issue is persistent in case it it?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it will work if you are careful to use Python2.7 and initiate a cloud project with the latest appengine Python2.7 SDK. I started a docker container for python:2 ("`docker run -it python:2 bash`"), installed the gcloud sdk, did pip install sympy, started the dev_appserver and got response from localhost which looks like success. The steps were:

```
    1  apt update
    2  apt install git
    3  pip install sympy
    4  pip install wget
    5  wget https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-sdk-271.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
    6  tar xvf google-cloud-sdk-271.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
    7  ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh
    8  ./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud init
    9  git clone git://github.com/sympy/sympy_gamma.git
   10  cd sympy_gamma
   11  git submodule init
   12  git submodule update
   13  python deploy.py --generate-only --generate-test 1000
   14  ../google-cloud-sdk/bin/dev_appserver.py . &
   15  wget http://localhost:8080
   16  cat index.html
```

Some output to show you the response I got:

```
root@185e6be609e8:/sympy_gamma# ../google-cloud-sdk/bin/dev_appserver.py . &
[1] 597
root@185e6be609e8:/sympy_gamma# WARNING  2019-11-14 11:42:41,426 appinfo.py:1657] django version "1.3" is deprecated, use one of: "1.4", "1.11"
INFO     2019-11-14 11:42:41,433 devappserver2.py:285] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2019-11-14 11:42:41,529 api_server.py:282] Starting API server at: http://localhost:35471
INFO     2019-11-14 11:42:41,616 dispatcher.py:263] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2019-11-14 11:42:41,618 admin_server.py:150] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
INFO     2019-11-14 11:42:43,657 instance.py:294] Instance PID: 611

root@185e6be609e8:/sympy_gamma# wget http://localhost:8080
--2019-11-14 11:42:55--  http://localhost:8080/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1, ::1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... INFO     2019-11-14 11:42:57,745 module.py:861] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 18014
200 OK
Length: 18014 (18K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

index.html                    100%[=================================================>]  17.59K  --.-KB/s    in 0.002s

2019-11-14 11:42:57 (9.62 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [18014/18014]

root@185e6be609e8:/sympy_gamma# INFO     2019-11-14 11:42:57,849 module.py:434] [default] Detected file changes:
  /sympy_gamma/index.html
INFO     2019-11-14 11:42:58,900 instance.py:294] Instance PID: 621

root@185e6be609e8:/sympy_gamma# cat index.html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>
SymPy Gamma
</title>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />



        <link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml"
              href="/static/opensearch.xml" title="SymPy Gamma" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
        <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"
                type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/static/js/base.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/static/js/card.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/static/js/plot.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/static/js/factordiagram.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/static/js/doc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/static/js/gamma.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
            MathJax.Hub.Config({
                jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],
                TeX: {
                    extensions: ["AMSmath.js", "AMSsymbols.js", "noErrors.js", "noUndefined.js"]
                },
                "HTML-CSS": {
                    minScaleAdjust: 100
                },
                menuSettings: {
                    context: "MathJax",
                    zoom: "Hover",
                    ALT: true
                },
                MathZoom: {
                    delay: 100
                },
                extensions: ["tex2jax.js"]
            });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML-full"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="menu">
            <a class="selected" href="/">Main</a>
            <a class="" href="/about/">About</a>
            <a href="https://live.sympy.org">SymPy Live</a>

            <div class="menu_right">
                <a href="/_ah/login?continue=http%3A//localhost%3A8080/">Login</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="gbh" style="left: 0px; opacity: 1; "></div>

    <div class="input">
        <h1><a href="/">
                <img src="/static/images/logo.png"
                     alt="SymPy Gamma logo" width="75" height="50" />
                SymPy Gamma
        </a></h1>
        <form action="/input/" method="GET">
            <input name="i" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" id="id_i" type="text" /><input class="input_field" type="submit" value="=" />
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="main">

        <div class="col example">
            <h2>Examples</h2>
            <a id="random-example" href="/random">Random Example</a>


            <div class="example-group">
            <i class="icon-angle-down"></i>
              <h3> Arithmetic</h3>

              <div class="contents">


                  <h4>Fractions</h4>

                  <ul>

                    <li><span>Simplify fractions</span> <a href="/input/?i=242/33">242/33</a></li>

                    <li><span>Rationalize repeating decimals</span> <a href="/input/?i=0.%5B123%5D">0.[123]</a></li>

                  </ul>


                  <h4>Approximations</h4>

                  <ul>

                    <li><a href="/input/?i=pi">pi</a></li>

                    <li><a href="/input/?i=E">E</a></li>

                    <li><a href="/input/?i=exp%28pi%29">exp(pi)</a></li>

                  </ul>

              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="example-group">
            <i class="icon-angle-down"></i>
              <h3> Algebra</h3>

              <div class="contents">


                  <ul>

                    <li><a href="/input/?i=x">x</a></li>

                    <li><a href="/input/?i=%28x%2B2%29/%28%28x%2B3%29%28x-4%29%29">(x+2)/((x+3)(x-4))</a></li>

                    <li><a href="/input/?i=simplify%28%28x%2A%2A2%20-%204%29/%28%28x%2B3%29%28x-2%29%29%29">simplify((x**2 - 4)/((x+3)(x-2)))</a></li>

                  </ul>


                  <h4>Polynomial and Rational Functions</h4>

                  <ul>

                    <li><span>Polynomial division</span> <a href="/input/?i=div%28x%2A%2A2%20-%204%20%2B%20x%2C%20x-2%29">div(x**2 - 4 + x, x-2)</a></li>

                    <li><span>Greatest common divisor</span> <a href="/input/?i=gcd%282%2Ax%2A%2A2%20%2B%206%2Ax%2C%2012%2Ax%29">gcd(2*x**2 + 6*x, 12*x)</a></li>

                    <li><span>&hellip;and least common multiple</span> <a href="/input/?i=lcm%282%2Ax%2A%2A2%20%2B%206%2Ax%2C%2012%2Ax%29">lcm(2*x**2 + 6*x, 12*x)</a></li>

                    <li><span>Factorization</span> <a href="/input/?i=factor%28x%2A%2A4/2%20%2B%205%2Ax%2A%2A3/12%20-%20x%2A%2A2/3%29">factor(x**4/2 + 5*x**3/12 - x**2/3)</a></li>

                    <li><span>Multivariate factorization</span> <a href="/input/?i=factor%28x%2A%2A2%20%2B%204%2Ax%2Ay%20%2B%204%2Ay%2A%2A2%29">factor(x**2 + 4*x*y + 4*y**2)</a></li>

                    <li><span>Symbolic roots</span> <a href="/input/?i=solve%28x%2A%2A2%20%2B%204%2Ax%2Ay%20%2B%204%2Ay%2A%2A2%29">solve(x**2 + 4*x*y + 4*y**2)</a></li>

                    <li><a href="/input/?i=solve%28x%2A%2A2%20%2B%204%2Ax%2Ay%20%2B%204%2Ay%2A%2A2%2C%20y%29">solve(x**2 + 4*x*y + 4*y**2, y)</a></li>

                    <li><span>Complex roots</span> <a href="/input/?i=solve%28x%2A%2A2%20%2B%204%2Ax%20%2B%20181%2C%20x%29">solve(x**2 + 4*x + 181, x)</a></li>

                    <li><span>Irrational roots</span> <a href="/input/?i=solve%28x%2A%2A3%20%2B%204%2Ax%20%2B%20181%2C%20x%29">solve(x**3 + 4*x + 181, x)</a></li>

                    <li><span>Systems of equations</span> <a href="/input/?i=solve_poly_system%28%5By%2A%2A2%20-%20x%2A%2A3%20%2B%201%2C%20y%2Ax%5D%2C%20x%2C%20y%29">solve_poly_system([y**2 - x**3 + 1, y*x], x, y)</a></li>

                  </ul>

              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="example-group">
            <i class="icon-angle-down"></i>
              <h3> Trigonometry</h3>

              <div class="contents">


                  <ul>

                    <li><a href="/input/?i=sin%282x%29">sin(2x)</a></li>

                    <li><a href="/input/?i=tan%281%20%2B%20x%29">tan(1 + x)</a></li>

                  </ul>

              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="example-group">
            <i class="icon-angle-down"></i>
              <h3> Calculus</h3>

              <div class="contents">


                  <h4>Limits</h4>

                  <ul>

                    <li><a href="/input/?i=limit%28tan%28x%29%2C%20x%2C%20pi/2%29">limit(tan(x), x, pi/2)</a></li>

                    <li><a href="/input/?i=limit%28tan%28x%29%2C%20x%2C%20pi/2%2C%20dir%3D%22-%22%29">limit(tan(x), x, pi/2, dir="-")</a></li>

                  </ul>


                  <h4>Derivatives</h4>

                  <ul>

                    <li><span>Derive the product rule</span> <a href="/input/?i=diff%28f%28x%29%2Ag%28x%29%2Ah%28x%29%29">diff(f(x)*g(x)*h(x))</a></li>

                    <li><span>&hellip;as well as the quotient rule</span> <a href="/input/?i=diff%28f%28x%29/g%28x%29%29">diff(f(x)/g(x))</a></li>

                    <li><span>Get steps for derivatives</span> <a href="/input/?i=diff%28%28sin%28x%29%20%2A%20x%5E2%29%20/%20%281%20%2B%20tan%28cot%28x%29%29%29%29">diff((sin(x) * x^2) / (1 + tan(cot(x))))</a></li>

                    <li><span>Multiple ways to derive functions</span> <a href="/input/?i=diff%28cot%28xy%29%2C%20y%29">diff(cot(xy), y)</a></li>

                    <li><span>Implicit derivatives, too</span> <a href="/input/?i=diff%28y%28x%29%5E2%20-%205sin%28x%29%2C%20x%29">diff(y(x)^2 - 5sin(x), x)</a></li>

                  </ul>


                  <h4>Integrals</h4>

                  <ul>

                    <li><a href="/input/?i=integrate%28tan%28x%29%29">integrate(tan(x))</a></li>

                    <li><span>Multiple variables</span> <a href="/input/?i=integrate%282%2Ax%20%2B%20y%2C%20y%29">integrate(2*x + y, y)</a></li>

                    <li><span>Limits of integration</span> <a href="/input/?i=integrate%282%2Ax%20%2B%20y%2C%20%28x%2C%201%2C%203%29%29">integrate(2*x + y, (x, 1, 3))</a></li>

                    <li><a href="/input/?i=integrate%282%2Ax%20%2B%20y%2C%20%28x%2C%201%2C%203%29%2C%20%28y%2C%202%2C%204%29%29">integrate(2*x + y, (x, 1, 3), (y, 2, 4))</a></li>

                    <li><span>Improper integrals</span> <a href="/input/?i=integrate%28tan%28x%29%2C%20%28x%2C%200%2C%20pi/2%29%29">integrate(tan(x), (x, 0, pi/2))</a></li>

                    <li><span>Exact answers</span> <a href="/input/?i=integrate%281/%28x%2A%2A2%20%2B%201%29%2C%20%28x%2C%200%2C%20oo%29%29">integrate(1/(x**2 + 1), (x, 0, oo))</a></li>

                    <li><span>Get steps for integrals</span> <a href="/input/?i=integrate%28exp%28x%29%20/%20%281%20%2B%20exp%282x%29%29%29">integrate(exp(x) / (1 + exp(2x)))</a></li>

                    <li><a href="/input/?i=integrate%281%20/%28%28x%2B1%29%28x%2B3%29%28x%2B5%29%29%29">integrate(1 /((x+1)(x+3)(x+5)))</a></li>

                    <li><a href="/input/?i=integrate%28%282x%2B3%29%2A%2A7%29">integrate((2x+3)**7)</a></li>

                  </ul>


                  <h4>Series</h4>

                  <ul>

                    <li><a href="/input/?i=series%28sin%28x%29%2C%20x%2C%20pi/2%29">series(sin(x), x, pi/2)</a></li>

                  </ul>

              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="example-group">
            <i class="icon-angle-down"></i>
              <h3> Number Theory</h3>

              <div class="contents">


                  <ul>

                    <li><a href="/input/?i=1006%21">1006!</a></li>

                    <li><a href="/input/?i=factorint%2812321%29">factorint(12321)</a></li>

                    <li><span>Calculate the 42<sup>nd</sup> prime</span> <a href="/input/?i=prime%2842%29">prime(42)</a></li>

                    <li><span>Calculate \( \varphi(x) \), the Euler totient function</span> <a href="/input/?i=totient%2842%29">totient(42)</a></li>

                    <li><a href="/input/?i=isprime%2812321%29">isprime(12321)</a></li>

                    <li><span>First prime greater than 42</span> <a href="/input/?i=nextprime%2842%29">nextprime(42)</a></li>

                  </ul>


                  <h4>Diophantine Equations</h4>

                  <ul>

                    <li><a href="/input/?i=diophantine%28x%2A%2A2%20-%204%2Ax%2Ay%20%2B%208%2Ay%2A%2A2%20-%203%2Ax%20%2B%207%2Ay%20-%205%29">diophantine(x**2 - 4*x*y + 8*y**2 - 3*x + 7*y - 5)</a></li>

                    <li><a href="/input/?i=diophantine%282%2Ax%20%2B%203%2Ay%20-%205%29">diophantine(2*x + 3*y - 5)</a></li>

                    <li><a href="/input/?i=diophantine%283%2Ax%2A%2A2%20%2B%204%2Ay%2A%2A2%20-%205%2Az%2A%2A2%20%2B%204%2Ax%2Ay%20-%207%2Ay%2Az%20%2B%207%2Az%2Ax%29">diophantine(3*x**2 + 4*y**2 - 5*z**2 + 4*x*y - 7*y*z + 7*z*x)</a></li>

                  </ul>

              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="example-group">
            <i class="icon-angle-down"></i>
              <h3> Discrete Mathematics</h3>

              <div class="contents">


                  <h4>Boolean Logic</h4>

                  <ul>

                    <li><a href="/input/?i=%28x%20%7C%20y%29%20%26%20%28x%20%7C%20%7Ey%29%20%26%20%28%7Ex%20%7C%20y%29">(x | y) & (x | ~y) & (~x | y)</a></li>

                    <li><a href="/input/?i=x%20%26%20%7Ex">x & ~x</a></li>

                  </ul>


                  <h4>Recurrences</h4>

                  <ul>

                    <li><span>Solve a recurrence relation</span> <a href="/input/?i=rsolve%28y%28n%2B2%29-y%28n%2B1%29-y%28n%29%2C%20y%28n%29%29">rsolve(y(n+2)-y(n+1)-y(n), y(n))</a></li>

                    <li><span>Specify initial conditions</span> <a href="/input/?i=rsolve%28y%28n%2B2%29-y%28n%2B1%29-y%28n%29%2C%20y%28n%29%2C%20%7By%280%29%3A%200%2C%20y%281%29%3A%201%7D%29">rsolve(y(n+2)-y(n+1)-y(n), y(n), {y(0): 0, y(1): 1})</a></li>

                  </ul>


                  <h4>Summation</h4>

                  <ul>

                    <li><a href="/input/?i=Sum%28k%2C%28k%2C1%2Cm%29%29">Sum(k,(k,1,m))</a></li>

                    <li><a href="/input/?i=Sum%28x%2A%2Ak%2C%28k%2C0%2Coo%29%29">Sum(x**k,(k,0,oo))</a></li>

                    <li><a href="/input/?i=Product%28k%2A%2A2%2C%28k%2C1%2Cm%29%29">Product(k**2,(k,1,m))</a></li>

                    <li><a href="/input/?i=summation%281/2%2A%2Ai%2C%20%28i%2C%200%2C%20oo%29%29">summation(1/2**i, (i, 0, oo))</a></li>

                    <li><a href="/input/?i=product%28i%2C%20%28i%2C%201%2C%20k%29%2C%20%28k%2C%201%2C%20n%29%29">product(i, (i, 1, k), (k, 1, n))</a></li>

                  </ul>

              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="example-group">
            <i class="icon-angle-down"></i>
              <h3> Plotting</h3>

              <div class="contents">


                  <ul>

                    <li><a href="/input/?i=plot%28sin%28x%29%20%2B%20cos%282x%29%29">plot(sin(x) + cos(2x))</a></li>

                    <li><span>Multiple plots</span> <a href="/input/?i=plot%28%5Bx%2C%20x%5E2%2C%20x%5E3%2C%20x%5E4%5D%29">plot([x, x^2, x^3, x^4])</a></li>

                    <li><span>Polar plots</span> <a href="/input/?i=plot%28r%3D1-sin%28theta%29%29">plot(r=1-sin(theta))</a></li>

                    <li><span>Parametric plots</span> <a href="/input/?i=plot%28x%3Dcos%28t%29%2C%20y%3Dsin%28t%29%29">plot(x=cos(t), y=sin(t))</a></li>

                    <li><span>Multiple plot types</span> <a href="/input/?i=plot%28y%3Dx%2Cy1%3Dx%5E2%2Cr%3Dcos%28theta%29%2Cr1%3Dsin%28theta%29%29">plot(y=x,y1=x^2,r=cos(theta),r1=sin(theta))</a></li>

                  </ul>

              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="example-group">
            <i class="icon-angle-down"></i>
              <h3> Miscellaneous</h3>

              <div class="contents">


                  <ul>

                    <li><span>Documentation for functions</span> <a href="/input/?i=factorial2">factorial2</a></li>

                    <li><a href="/input/?i=sympify">sympify</a></li>

                    <li><a href="/input/?i=bernoulli">bernoulli</a></li>

                  </ul>

              </div>

            </div>


            <p>… and more: see
            the <a href="https://docs.sympy.org">documentation</a> to learn
            about the full range of SymPy's capabilities.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <p>
        SymPy Gamma version 1000, deployed on 29/08/20 14:20:46.
        </p>

        <p>
        &copy; 2013 SymPy Development Team. This project is
        open-source: <a href="https://github.com/sympy/sympy_gamma/">
            SymPy Gamma on Github</a>.
        </p>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
root@185e6be609e8:/sympy_gamma#
```

Comment: i follow your code line by line but in web page localhost refused to connection error occurs.
 [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/wAUIBzX.png) Error image

Comment: whenever i run the **../google-cloud-sdk/bin/dev_appserver.py . & wget http://localhost:8080 ** it will give me error can not assign requested address. [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/Ty5Uysk.png) can you help me?

Comment: try this command first: `../google-cloud-sdk/bin/dev_appserver.py .` and check that the server starts.

Comment: i m run both the way but server not responding.